# Change the title of date_popup filed in custom form

Tags: forms, datetime

I'm building a custom form in Drupal 7 and i need to use the date_popup widget in it. It all works as expected, except the title of the field.

My code is:

```
  $form['filter']['start_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#date_format' => 'd-m-Y',
    '#title' => t('Start date'),
  );

  $form['filter']['end_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#date_format' => 'd-m-Y',
    '#title' => t('End date'),
  );
```

But it keeps showing the default label "Date" for the field, as you can see on in the picture below. [image: date_popup widget wrong title]

Can you please let me know how can i put **Start date** and **End date** as field labels instead of just **Date**, or correct me if i'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 4):

Just use the following code:

```
'#date_label_position' => 'none',
```

your code :

```
$form['filter']['start_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#date_format' => 'd-m-Y',
    '#title' => t('Start date'),
    '#date_label_position' => 'none',
  );

  $form['filter']['end_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#date_format' => 'd-m-Y',
    '#title' => t('End date'),
    '#date_label_position' => 'none',
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can unset the labels like below:

```
function <module_name>_date_popup_process_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if ($element['#name'] == '<fieldname>') {
    unset($element['date']['#title']);  
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to unset the title, i just want to use titles i need, not default one.

Comment: The above code should unset the default

Comment: This is the best place to update the title, simply don't use the `unset` part.

Answer (score 2):

Solution i came up with is following:

```
  $form['filter']['start_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#date_format' => 'd-m-Y',
    '#title' => t('Start date'), //set desired title
    '#title_display' => 'invisible', //but hide it from showing
  );
```

Next, implement hook_element_info_alter():

```
function my_module_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  if (isset($type['date_popup'])) {
    $type['date_popup']['#process'][] = 'my_module_date_popup_process'; //name of the process function, can be anything
  }
}
```

and then set default title equals the title from form element:

```
//process function called from hook_element_info_alter
function my_module_date_popup_process($element, $form_state, $complete_form) {
  if ($complete_form['form_id']['#id'] == 'edit-my-form-id') {
    $element['date']['#title'] = $element['#title'];
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Result is like this:
[image]

Comment: Although this works, you can do it in one function by implementing `hook_date_popup_process_alter()` and set the title there.

Answer (score 1):

I only got this to work in Drupal 7.43 by hacking the date_popup module.

I added the following code in line 336 to the file date_popup.module found in sites/all/modules/contrib/date/date_popup/date_popup.module (your installation might omit the contrib folder)

```
// Fixes bug where title wasn't getting updated in hook
if (isset($element['#title'])) {
  $element['date']['#title'] = $element['#title'];
  $element['#title_display']  =  'invisible';
}
```

Hope this helps someone, I took a long time to figure it out.