# No default value for '#type' => 'date'?

Tags: forms, datetime

is there a way to configure a date form so it has no default value?
Setting the default value to NULL sets the default value automatically to the current date.

```
  /**
   * @return array
   */
  public function getFormFieldSampDate() {
    return [
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#title' => t('Date of Sampling '),
      '#default_value' => self::dateStringToArray($this->sampling_date),
    ];
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Pretty simple, don't provide a `#default_value` key.

Comment: That does not work for me. The API says:  "The #default_value will be today's date if no value is supplied." Thats sounds like there can't be no default date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1) Install [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module.

Step 2) Enable the **Date Popup** module (comes with the [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module).

Step 3) Add code like the following:

```
  $form['date'] = [
    '#date_label' => 'above',
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#date_format' => 'm/d/Y',
    '#datepicker_options' => [
      // limits date picker so no future date can be picked.
      // remove this section if you want to allow future dates.
      'maxDate' => "+0D", 
    ],
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => [
      'autocomplete' => 'off',
    ],
  ];
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked very well. Is there a simple solution to disable or change the description to the fields?

Comment: @Xyarvius see [Change the title of date_popup filed in custom form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153677/change-the-title-of-date-popup-filed-in-custom-form/153678)

Comment: Thanks. Worked very well.